# What all goes in my Trainer Passport?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

Right now, I've got 6/15 pages of my Trainer Passport filled out:

1. Official Pokémon Trainer
2. Melemele Trial Completion
3. Akala Trial Completion
4. Ula'ula Trial Completion
5. Poni Trial Completion
6. Island Challenge Completion

The rest are blank.

What are the other pages for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Serebii.net](http://www.serebii.net/sunmoon/trainerpassport.shtml), the 15 pages are:

**Official Pokémon Trainer:**   You took the first step as a Pokémon Trainer!
**Melemele Trial Completion:**  Complete the Melemele Island Trial
**Akala Trial Completion:** Complete the Akala Island Trial
**Ula’ula Trial Completion:**   Complete the Ula'ula Island Trial
**Poni Trial Completion:**  Complete the Poni Island Trial
**Island Challenge Completion:** With this stamp, all Pokémon will obey your every command.
**Melemele Pokédex Completion:**    You registered all Pokémon on Melemele Island!
**Akala Pokédex Completion:**   You registered all Pokémon on Akala Island!
**Ula’ula Pokédex Completion:** You registered all Pokémon on Ula’ula Island!
**Poni Pokédex Completion:**    You registered all Pokémon on Poni Island!
**Alola Pokédex Completion:**   You registered all Pokémon in the Alola region!
**50 Consecutive Single Battle Wins:**  You achieved 50 consecutive wins in Single Battles at the Battle Tree.
**50 Consecutive Double Battle Wins:**  You achieved 50 consecutive wins in Double Battles at the Battle Tree.
**Poké Finder Pro:**    You obtained the final version of the Poké Finder!
**50 Consecutive Multi Battle Wins:**   You achieved 50 consecutive wins in Multi Battles at the Battle Tree.

Hopefully that explains your question